# What does "original already" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

An artist called 5haus sent a song to an artist called deadmau5 on his twitch channel. When deadmau5 read the sender name (5haus) he said: "original already", does it have a positive or negative meaning? I think that possibly it has a positive meaning because maybe he liked the name, or it could have also a negative meaning thinking about 5haus "copied" his name style. Or maybe is that a joke? Thanks for your comments!

Comment: It's probably sarcastic, and they're trying to say that they can already guess what the sender's song will sound like (probably unoriginal) as the sender couldn't have even thought up an original nickname.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got it now. The good thing is that he liked the song after what he said so it was like a surprise for him and also for his audience.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually surprising. However, how do you know that's not exactly what they were talking about – after all, the author makes music they themselves like, don't they? Therefore, if they've liked it, it might be because it's so similar to their own music! : )

Answer (score 1):

One online dictionary has this definition of already, stating that it is a North American usage

> used after a word or phrase to express impatience.
>
> "just stop already, no one feels sorry for you

Another has

> used to show that you are losing patience and want someone to stop doing something or to do something more quickly:
>
> Enough already! I heard you the first time!

I've also seen a suggestion that **already** can be used as punctuation, instead of a comma already to give a small pause in a sentence.

When speaking, the degree of impatience being conveyed would be very dependent upon the tone of voice, it can sound either extremely disparaging or almost self deprecating; mocking oneself for being impatient.

The Urban Dictionary also gives another usage:

> Houston, TX's gangsta resident way to say 'Fo Sho' or 'Yeah'.

In your example it's very hard to know what was intended. For sure the fact that the name is **not* original is being commented on with a degree of sarcasm, but whether it's in a friendly way or an irritated or condescending manner is not obvious to me.

Comment: Haha, *already* was employed with the normal, Standard-English meaning. I mean, maybe I'm misconstruing it severely, but by my lights, they're simply saying, "**so far** [I've seen] nothing original [from this person]" (the "nothing" bit is the sarcasm).

Comment: Guys, thank you for your comments. Something to add is that he is from Canada. Also for me, it was sarcastic but can’t figure out if it was friendly or not. Here you have the video to listen to it, I forgot to put the link: https://youtu.be/6vc9R0mI6Yg